# Is there any way to stop Android from changing "I want $5.00" into "I want$ 5.00"?

Tags: languages, auto-correct

I don't even know why it does this, tbh, since pretty much everyone writes $xx.xx and not anything else, such as xx.xxUS$ or anything like that.

Note: Turning off Auto-Punctuate does not fix this problem, so this is my hail mary attempt to get rid of this "feature."  :P

(Edit: My phone is a Motorola Droid 2 Global.  The problem exists no matter if the physical or on-screen keyboard is used.)

Comment: Never seen either of my phones do anything like that, on ithe default keyboard, or Swype. What phone and keyboard are you using?

Comment: @GAThrawn I've got a Motorola Droid 2 Global.  Added that to the original post to increase visibility.

Comment: @Michael Do you get the problem using the physical keyboard, or the soft-keyboard on the touch-screen or both? I've only ever used Androids with soft-keyboards, but on those at least there are a lot of keyboard replacements available in the Market, many have their own auto-correct rules.

Comment: Are you using the English language in Android or some other language?

Comment: @GAThrawn The problem exists both on the physical and on-screen keyboard.

Comment: @Bryan Yes, the English language is selected in the Language  & Keyboard options section.

Comment: I also experience this on a Droid2 Global, so @Michael is not delusional. It happens for me with double quotes following a space, which is absolutely infuriating.

Comment: Yep... quite a few punctuation characters perform like this, it seems.  It's good for periods, commas, etc., but not some others: &, *, -, + ... and I find $ and " to be especially annoying.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with Stock keyboard app/service. It can't be fixed by normal means. Simply, use third-party soft keyboard apps viz. [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey.phone.trial), [Go Keyboard EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard), [A.I. Type Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aitype.android), [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) etc.